# How to add new instructions to exisiting VersionedTransaction?

Tags: versionedtransactions, transaction-instructions, priority-fees

For context, the goal of the code shown below is to take the transaction given by the JUP api for a limit order and adding both the increased compute unit price instruction and a more recent blockhash.

So currently the code executes perfectly fine, but I feel the way that I've written it seems very messy and could cause future problems if things become more complex. I would just like to have some clarity on what the best method would be to take an exisiting Versioned Transaction and adding more instructions to it, how I should handle the program_id indexes, the account keys, etc. Thanks in advance for help on the topic.

```
priorityFee = set_compute_unit_price(gas)
rawTransaction = VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(apiTransaction))
accountKeys = rawTransaction.message.account_keys
lengthAccountKeys = len(accountKeys)
accountKeys.append(priorityFee.program_id)

rawInstructions = rawTransaction.message.instructions

newInstruction = CompiledInstruction(
    program_id_index=lengthAccountKeys,
    data=priorityFee.data,
    accounts=rawInstructions[0].accounts,
)

rawInstructions.append(newInstruction)

newTransactionMessage = Message.new_with_compiled_instructions(
    num_required_signatures=rawTransaction.message.header.num_required_signatures,
    num_readonly_signed_accounts=rawTransaction.message.header.num_readonly_signed_accounts,
    num_readonly_unsigned_accounts=rawTransaction.message.header.num_readonly_unsigned_accounts,
    account_keys=accountKeys,
    recent_blockhash=recentBlockhash,
    instructions=rawInstructions,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it definitely looks brittle, this might be your best option! Just a few small things I'd recommend:

- the compute unit instruction requires no accounts, so you can do:

```
newInstruction = CompiledInstruction(
    program_id_index=lengthAccountKeys,
    data=priorityFee.data,
    accounts=[],
)
```

- (Unless I've forgotten how Python works), you've modified the transaction in-place with a compiled instruction, so it should be ok to sign that one as is. You might just need to add `1` to `num_readonly_unsigned_accounts` to reflect adding the compute budget program.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!